# Clear my input in jquery / javascript

Tags: jquery, css

I want to clear my uploaded file with jquery. I tried this but not working.

```js
var $el = $('#specialImg1');
$el.wrap('<form>').closest('form').get(0).reset();
$el.unwrap();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input id="specialImg1" type="file" name="specialImg" onchange="previewSpecialImage(1);" width="3000" height="2500" required="" class="user-error" aria-invalid="true">
</form>
```

Comment: Clear it how and when?

Comment: Why are you adding a `form` element when you already have a `form` element? That is, `$el.closest('form')[0].reset()` should work fine. You can't have nested forms in HTML, so that could be why it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Its already working. Try by loging it in console. Instead of the method you have written, you could simply use `$('#specialImg1').val('');`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        function clearit() {
            var $el = $('#specialImg1');
            $el.wrap('<form>').closest('form').get(0).reset();
            $el.unwrap();
            console.log($("#specialImg1").val());
        }
        function upload(){
            console.log($("#specialImg1").val());
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <form>
        <input id="specialImg1" type="file" name="specialImg" width="3000" height="2500" required="" class="user-error" aria-invalid="true" onchange="upload()">
    </form>
    <button onclick="clearit()">clearit</button>
</body>

</html>
```